# How do I get a cleat that's stuck in a pedal, detached from the shoe, out?

Tags: pedals, spd, cleat, pedals-clipless

While out riding on my XC bike today, I encountered an issue with my cleat: The connector between the cleat and the shoe - the part that you screw into - died, and I lost a screw. So I had the shoe attached to the pedal, unable to unclip - because I was able to completely turn the shoe around without the cleat detaching. (The other cleat still worked, and I noticed that I couldn't unclip in a safe enough situation that I avoided biting the dust.)

When I got home, I detached the shoe by turning it around enough times that it unscrewed. (Trying to tighten it by screwing it the other way didn't work.) Unfortunately, now the shoe is detached, leaving the cleat itself still inside the pedal, with a single screw sticking out:

[image: image of cleat stuck in pedal]

**How do I get the cleat loose?**

Comment: Consider adding a small dab of loctite or superglue to the threads on reassembling, and torque to the suggested value.   I've also started carrying a spare bolt/washer in my on-bike kit whereever I have cleats.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Slacken off any tension adjusting screw first**

Your goal is to apply torque to the cleat as you would with your foot in a shoe.  So essentially you need something like a gigantic flat screwdriver.   I have a mini crowbar that would do the job, for example, but if you have any metal tyre levers they might be big enough.

Comment: Just want to add:  counting the turns as you release the tensioning screw is the easiest way to get it properly tensioned once you've extracted the cleat.

Answer (score 10):

Use water-pump-pliers or locking pliers (vise-grip). Grip the cleat and turn it either clock-wise or anti-clock-wise

Alternatively a medium sized screwdriver used as a lever at the rear 'nose' of the cleat will pop it out. Mind fingers and eyes, though! It might be a good idea for both methods to reduce the spring tension of the pedal by turning the adjustment screw as far to the '-' sign as possible with a hex key.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are good, but I'll add these possible options if you're short of the tools they require:

- Use an appropriately sized punch or drift and tap the cleat out with
  a hammer. Hit the back but from the side, you need to be pretty handy but a quick blow in just the right spot should do it. If you can't figure out what I
  mean, then it's best you don't try it.
- Unscrew the Phillip's CSK screws and see what
  happens. As the cleat is under compression, the front bit might pop
  off with a wee bit of gusto at some point. If you
  see any coloured residue on the threads of those screws afterwards
  that is some kind of threadlock, best apply the same when you
  reinstall them.

An amount of lubricant around the rear of the cleat would likely help in most of these discussed cases.

Comment: I wouldn't take the pedal apart. The springs are under considerable load.

Comment: Looking at [a diagram](https://forums.mtbr.com/attachments/shimano/323181d1199226054-shimano-540-vs-xt-pedals-20080101-pd-m540-pedal.jpg) of a similar pedal, it doesn't appear that the "toe plate" (4 on diagram) has anything to do with the springs. It looks like it could be easily removed and re-attached. Not completely sure though, maybe someone with more experience could chime in.

Comment: IIRC the spring on the other side of the pedal pushes against the pedal itself - in that case, the toe plate is under no load will be easy to remove & replace. Just check it visually, you should be able to see it

Comment: The screws are certainly _not_ Philips headed but JIS screws. They don't look like Philips. As far as I know, Shimano never used Philips.

Comment: @gschenk, ok, feel free to edit the answer and advise the requirement for a JIS driver. Meanwhile, some people may make do with Phillips in its absence.

Comment: @gschenk, meanwhile I read up more on JIS, while I would agree that being a Japanese product you may suspect they would opt for the JIS standard, I do note that there is no telltale 'dot' on the screws (I looked up higher resolution photos of what I suspect is the same model pedal online). Can you elaborate on how you're so certain? Perhaps it's something in the profile of the '+' you can see? Either way, I think Phillips would work fine in this case.

Comment: Lamar I'm not as certain anymore. It is mostly the looks. I've checked it's Japanese made only after that. Phillips heads are quite rare today because they cannot be used well with automation. Pozidriv is for most cases a better choice. There's also no Pozidriv sign on the screws. I think it would be strange for Shimano to use them there while they use JIS for other products (eg limit screws). I'd usually resort to calling them cross head screws to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Correction: Pozidriv in my previous comment is wrong. There are apparently a plethora of similar interfaces by the screw company behind Phillips. I've no idea what is typically used when we see a recessed cruciform screw head that isn't JIS. (three cheers for hexalobular screws!)

Comment: @gschenk I've had zero issues using Phillips on those screws. They neither have the JIS dot nor the Pozidriv cross. You only need 5Nm or so, not 50. The XTR pedals use Torx.